# Jquery not working after page one on website with Infinite Scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a newsfeed with infinite scroll implemented. You can comment on activities on the newsfeed by clicking a comment-bubble, which slides down the add a comment form.

The problem is that the comment-bubble slide down works only for the activities loaded on the first page, not for the ones that load via AJAX with the infinite scroll afterwards.

This is the JQuery for the slidedown.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".comment-bubble").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".activity").find(".add-comment").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try `$(document).on('click', ".comment-bubble",function(e){ //code here });`

Comment: Thank you Mohit Arora! That worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to attach click events to the the comment bubble which are loaded via ajax. As you are loading them through ajax the event handler is not attached to them.After you ajax is done do something like this

```
click_function= function(){
  //some code    
};
$(".comment-bubble").on('click', click_function);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
$(function() {
    $(".comment-bubble").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".activity").find(".add-comment").slideToggle();
        });
    });
});
```

Or if you are having event binding issues...

```
$(function() {
    $(".comment-bubble").each(function() {
        $(this).bind("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".activity").find(".add-comment").slideToggle();
        });
    });
});
```